# How do I set up Python canopen with the usb2can interface?

Tags: python, canopen

I am trying to use the Python `canopen` library and the `USB2CAN` adapter to communicate with a `canopen` 402 device.

So far I have not been able to get past the most basic example of defining the network.

The script crashes consistently on the error:

> "AttributeError: 'Usb2canBus' object has no attribute '_filters' "

The documentation for python-can mentions that filters are not implemented for the `usb2can` device, but seems to imply that it should still be usable.

Has anyone been successful in using the usb2can adapter with Python?

I have not been able to find any examples, can someone point me to one?

Below is one of the very basic examples included in the python canopen docs.

This fails with the filters error described above, as do most other operations that I have tried.

```
import canopen
import time

#define network
network = canopen.Network()

#establish connection
network.connect(channel='ED000200', bustype='usb2can', bitrate=500000)

# This will attempt to read an SDO from nodes 1 - 127
network.scanner.search()
# We may need to wait a short while here to allow all nodes to respond
time.sleep(0.05)
for node_id in network.scanner.nodes:
    print("Found node %d!" % node_id)

#close connection
network.disconnect()
```

For this example I expect a list of nodes on the network to be printed, possibly an empty list because no nodes have been added.

Instead I am getting the error:

> AttributeError: 'Usb2canBus' object has no attribute '_filters'

Answer (score 0):

May your network.connect line is wrong.

I use the USB/CAN from seeedstudio on a Windows PC and this what I did:

```
network.connect(bustype='seeedstudio', channel='COM8', baudrate=2000000, bitrate=1000000)
```